# How can I make "index_col" from pandas.read_csv case insensitive when parsing dates from different CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse dates from different csv files then use the parsed dates as my dataframe's index column like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv, parse_dates=True, index_col="date")
```

But I need `index_col` to be case insensitive because some csv files have "DATE" and some don't

I've tried myself but can't figure out a way after googling and would really like some help if it's even possible

Comment: You could just check if the CSV contains "date" or "DATE" and adjust your code accordingly with an if/else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the CSV first then make all the columns lowercase (which is easier to type anyway).

```
pd.read_csv(csv, parse_dates=True).rename(columns=str.lower).set_index('date')
```